# Пропадают картинки svg на сайте wordpress

Tags: wordpress, svg, cms

У меня на компе все окей отображается, стоит мне зайти на мобилку то картинки svg пропадают а jpeg и png остаются.

Comment: наверное мобильный браузер не умеет в свг-спрайты)

Comment: Зашёл с телефона, вроде все картинки на месте. Кеш в браузере телефона?